# Is it possible to know if function was called from a reference?

Tags: javascript

Both of these calls will alert "hello" but is it possible to know how it was called?

```
function Test() {
    this.foo = this;
}

Test.prototype.bar = function (value) {
    // Check if it was called through foo
    alert(value);
}

var test = new Test();

test.foo.bar('hello');
test.bar('hello');
```

Basically I want to know if it was called from test or test.foo.

Is it possible?

Comment: Since `test === test.foo`, there's no possible way of knowing.

Comment: Good question.  I don't think this is possible, though.

Comment: not anymore (it used to be, but the API that made it work has been deprecated). The real question is why you need to know this? Let's solve that problem properly instead =)

Comment: It may be possible thanks to a debugger or a profiler. (for example firebug)

Comment: Functions are **always** "called from a reference".

Comment: @Pointy How would you phrase the question?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Well, basically I'm making an API service which will use the syntax API.posts.id(123).comments.id(456).get() to make a GET to /posts/123/comments/456. I might post another question regarding that though since I'm very interested in knowing if the above is possible at all.

Comment: @user2906759 well I'm not sure. There is absolutely no distinct relationship between a function and any particular reference to it. Any copy of the reference to the function is as good as another.

Comment: @user2906759 that sounds like a very different problem. Just use proper objects and call `var url = API.formURL()` which then uses delegation to get that URL you want, using a variation on `formURL: function() { return myname + "/" + child.formURL() }`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks but I'm not sure I understand your example. I would prefer not to introduce any other methods. At the moment I have API.posts.id(123).comments().id(456).get() working but I would like to get rid of the () on comments.

Comment: you should prefer to do things the right way, not stick to what works even when you run into problems with that approach =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Why is it the wrong way? Where can I read about your formURL approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commented first, but actually that's the answer XD

No, it it not possible. The reason is because by writing `this.foo = this`, you are ensuring that `this.foo` and `this` are the exact same thing. Since they are the same thing, trying to tell them apart is rather like this surreal joke:

> Q: What's the difference between a duck?
>   A: One of its legs is both the same.

Comment: +1 Because I knew the duck question but not the answer.